# Problema con recursividad en C

Tags: c, funciones, recursión

En un ejercicio se me pidió calcular la potencia del número 3 usando funciones recursivas. Pero cuando corro el programa sólo llega hasta la parte donde se ejecuta la función y no hace nada más.

Estoy casi seguro que el problema está en la definición de la función, ya probé con una variable local, y con `return( 3 * Potencia(p - 1) )` directamente pero todas terminan igual.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
/*  Escriba una funcion recursiva que calcule el valor de 3
a la potencia de otro numero. Por ejemplo, si se le pasa 4
la función regresará 81. */

#include<stdio.h>

int Potencia(int a); //prototipo de funcion
int x = 3, p,z;
int main() {

    printf("Ingrese el numero de potencia que desea: \n");
    scanf("%d",&p);
    z = Potencia(x); //lamada de la función
    
    printf("El numero 3 a la potencia %d es: %d",p,z);
    return 0;
}

int Potencia(int a) {  //definición de función
    //potencia = p
    
    int u;  //variable local
    if(p==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
       u=3*(Potencia(p-1)); //si p=2, u=3(Potencia(2-1)) ---> u = 3(Potencia(1-1) = 1 =
       return u;            //si p=2, u=3(3(1)) = 9         
    }

}
```

Comment: El parámetro de la función `Potencia()` no debería llamarse `a`, sino `p`, pues con ese nombre lo usas luego en su interior. Por otro lado yo creo que esa función debería recibir dos parámetros: el número a elevar (digamos `x`), y el exponente (digamos `p`). Entonces si `p` es 1, retornas 1 y en caso contrario retornas `a*Potencia(a, p-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te sea útil:

```
/* Escriba una función recursiva que calcule el valor de 3
 * a la potencia de otro numero. Por ejemplo, si se le pasa 4
 * la función regresará 81. */

#include <stdio.h>

int Potencia(int base, int exponente); //Prototipo de la función.

int main()
{
    int base = 3, exponente, potencia;
    int exponente_negativo = 0;
    
    printf("Ingrese el exponente que desea: \n");
    scanf("%d", &exponente);
    
    if (exponente < 0) //Para exponente negativo.
    {
        exponente = exponente * -1;
        exponente_negativo = 1;
    }
    
    if (0 == exponente)
    {
        potencia = 1;
    }
    else if (1 == exponente)
    {
        potencia = base;
    }
    else
    {
        potencia = Potencia(base, exponente); //Llamada de la función.
    }
    
    printf("El número %d a la potencia", base);
    
    if (1 == exponente_negativo)
    {
        printf(" %d es: %f\n", -exponente, (1.0 / potencia));
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" %d es: %d\n", exponente, potencia);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

int Potencia(int base, int exponente) //Definición de la función.
{
    /* Para base = 3 y exponente = 4:
     * 
     * [1] = Potencia(3, 2) -> 3 * 3
     *   [2] = Potencia(3, 3) -> 3 * [1]
     *     [3] = Potencia(3, 4) -> 3 * [2]
     * 
     * potencia = [3] */
    
    if (2 == exponente) //Se llego al final.
    {
        return base * base;
    }
    else
    {
        return base * Potencia(base, exponente - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cada vez que escribes una línea de código sin tabular, se muere un gatito de youtube

Answer (score 0):

Espero te pueda servir esta solucion

comenzamos declarando nuestro prototipo de la funcion, luego del main declaramos variables locales p y z, luego agregamos un do while para garantizar que solo se introduzcan numeros positivos "esto se puede hacer en cualquier codigo que necesite una validacion de esta manera", llamamos a la funcion y le pasamos la variable p que corresponde a la cantidad de recursiones que ara el algorimo y se lo asignamos a la variable z, ese valor luego se imprime como resultado.

/* nuestra funcion recursiva recibe el entero a, declaramos la variable u local, luego si a==0 retornamos 1 sino a u le asignamos 3 x el llamado de la funcion potencia y le restamos 1 a la variable a, si es igual a 3, tendremos 3 llamados y luego cuando a sea 0 retornamos en, y desde ese momento comienza la operacion. primera recursion/u=3x1,segunda recursion/u=3x3,tercera recursion/u=3x9, y por ultimo retornamos 27.

Escriba una funcion recursiva que calcule el valor de 3 a la potencia de otro numero. Por ejemplo, si se le pasa 4 la función regresará 81.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int Potencia(int a); //prototipo de funcion.
 int main(){
     //Variable local
     int p,z;
     do{
          printf("Ingrese el numero de potencia que desea: ");
          scanf("%d",&p);
     }while(p<1);
     z = Potencia(p); //lamada de la funcion

     printf("El numero 3 a la potencia %d es: %d",p,z);
     return 0;
 }
 
 int Potencia(int a) //definicion de funcion
 { 
     //variable local
     int u;
     if(a==0){
        return 1;
     }else{
         u=3*(Potencia(a-1));
         return u;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Por favor explica tu código, esto siempre se agrade, puede haber concepto o funciones que el OP no entienda, una explicación resuelve varios problemas :)

Comment: @Christian, excelente, ya he dejado una breve explicación de el código. Gracias

Comment: Muy bien amigo, asi esta mejor :)